# How can parse xml response in to variable and store in to table using php and mysql?

Tags: php, xml, dom

How can I parse an XML response into variable and store in to table?

XML response is fetched with the following script:

```
<?php
require_once 'db.php';
define( 'HOST', 'https://gateway.autodns.com');
define( 'XML_FILE', 'test.xml' );
$xml = implode( "", file(XML_FILE) );
header( 'Content-Type: text/xml' );
echo requestCurl( $xml );
function requestCurl( $data )
{
    $ch = curl_init( HOST );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE );
    if( !$data = curl_exec( $ch )) {
        echo 'Curl execution error.', curl_error( $ch ) ."\n"; return FALSE;
    }
    curl_close( $ch );
    return $data;
}

$api_insert = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO api name, created, payable VALUES ('', '', '')");
?>
```

`echo requestCurl( $xml );` prints XML content shown below. I need to take `<name>`, `<payable>` and `<created>` element values for each domain and store them into a table.

**XML**

```
<response>
<result>
<data>
<summary>2</summary>
<domain>
<name>facebook.bayern</name>
<payable>2017-05-06 13:34:46</payable>
<domainsafe>false</domainsafe>
<dnssec>false</dnssec>
<owner>
<user>dhabi</user>
<context>4</context>
</owner>
<created>2015-05-06 13:34:46</created>
<updated>2016-12-20 11:29:10</updated>
</domain>
<domain>
<name>google.com</name>
<payable>2017-04-08 22:04:04</payable>
<domainsafe>false</domainsafe>
<dnssec>false</dnssec>
<owner>
<user>dhabi</user>
<context>4</context>
</owner>
<created>2016-04-08 22:04:05</created>
<updated>2016-12-20 17:44:39</updated>
</domain>
</data>
<status>
<code>S0105</code>
<text>Domaindaten wurden erfolgreich ermittelt.</text>
<type>success</type>
</status>
</result>
<stid>20161221-app4-40522</stid>
</response>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [DOM extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php):

```
// $xml = 'XML content';
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$expr = '/response/result//domain';
$domains = $xpath->query($expr);

foreach ($domains as $d) {
  $props = [];
  foreach ($d->childNodes as $child) {
    $props[$child->nodeName] = $child->nodeValue;
  }

  if (
    isset($props['name']) &&
    isset($props['payable']) &&
    isset($props['created'])
  )
  {
    printf(
      "Name: %s\nPayable: %s\nCreated: %s\n\n",
      $props['name'],
      $props['payable'],
      $props['created']
    );
  }
}
```

The XPath expression selects all (`//`) `domain` nodes under `/response/result/`. `DOMXPath::query` returns a `Traversable` list of nodes into `$domains` variable.

The next loop fetches `DOMElement` items from `$domains`, and the inner loop collects the child nodes into `$props` array. If all elements (`name`, `payable`, and `created`) are collected, `printf` prints them to the standard output.

*Output*

```
Name: facebook.bayern
Payable: 2017-05-06 13:34:46
Created: 2015-05-06 13:34:46

Name: google.com
Payable: 2017-04-08 22:04:04
Created: 2016-04-08 22:04:05
```

---

Instead of fetching all child nodes, you may fetch only specific elements using an extra call to XPath:

```
$children = $xpath->query('*[self::name or self::payable or self::created]', $d);
if ($children->length != 3) {
  continue;
}
```

Note, the domain element is passed as a context node for the relative XPath expression.

---

In order to store the values into database using MySQLi replace the `printf` call with the following:

```
$sql = sprintf(
  'INSERT INTO `api` (name, created, payable) VALUES ("%s", "%s", "%s")',
  $mysqli->real_escape_string($props['name']),
  $mysqli->real_escape_string($props['payable']),
  $mysqli->real_escape_string($props['created'])
);
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
```

Comment: Thanks. When I print `"printf(
      "Name: %s\nPayable: %s\nCreated: %s\n\n",
      $props['name'],
      $props['payable'],
      $props['created']
    );"` I am getting error `XML Parsing Error: no root element found
Location: https://localhost/auto_dns_api/api.php
Line Number 1, Column 1:` Do you know why it is showing like this.

Comment: `$xml = requestCurl( $xml )` correct? If I am defining like this getting error like `XML Parsing Error: syntax error
Location: https://localhost/auto_dns_api/api.php
Line Number 1, Column 1:Name: facebook.bayern`

Comment: @samsam, [this](https://eval.in/701889) is a working code. You need to set `$xml` variable to a string with XML downloaded from the remote host

Answer (score 2):

PHP has a nifty method called `simplexml_load_string` and what it does is it loads an XML structured string into an easy to use object.  Let’s say you have a string variable called `$xmlResponse` that has the following properly formatted XML in it:

$xmlResponse

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<business>
    <company>Code Blog</company>
    <owner>Nic Raboy</owner>
    <employees>
        <employee>
            <firstname>Nic</firstname>
            <lastname>Raboy</lastname>
        </employee>
        <employee>
            <firstname>Maria</firstname>
            <lastname>Campos</lastname>
        </employee>
    </employees>
</business>
```

Doing the following in PHP will give us a very nice object to work with:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlResponse);
```

[Reference](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/09/parse-xml-response-php/)

Answer (score 0):

Make XML to array using XML parse 
example below

```
$simple = "<para><note>simple note</note></para>";
$p = xml_parser_create();
xml_parse_into_struct($p, $simple, $vals, $index);
xml_parser_free($p);
echo "Index array\n";
print_r($index);
echo "\nVals array\n";
print_r($vals);
```

Comment: I tried this method but getting some error. `$simple = requestCurl( $xml );
$p = xml_parser_create();
xml_parse_into_struct($p, $simple, $vals, $index);
xml_parser_free($p);
echo "Index array\n";
print_r($index);
echo "\nVals array\n";
print_r($vals);` Error is  `XML Parsing Error: syntax error
Location: https://localhost/auto_dns_api/api.php
Line Number 1, Column 1:Index array`